# When is the group homomorphism injective or surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I am looking the following two questions:

1) For which natural numbers $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ is there is there an injective group homomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}, +)\rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, +)$ ?

2) For which natural numbers $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ is there is there an surjective group homomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}, +)\rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, +)$ ?

$$$$

So that the group homomorphism is injective $m$ has to be smaller than/equal to $n$. And so that the group homomorphism is surjective $n$ has to smaller than/equal to $m$.

Is my idea correct?

Comment: Half. You also need the mapping to preserve the addition operation in the domain and codomain respectively.

Comment: And how can we choose the n and m such that this holds? @xbh

Comment: You have no idea? Hint: division.

Comment: Do you mean that it must hold $m \mid n$ and $n \mid m$ respectively? @xbh

Answer (score 3):

If such an injective homomorphism  $f: \Bbb Z /m \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z / n\Bbb Z$ exists, then $f(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)$ forms a subgroup in $\Bbb Z/ n \Bbb Z$, now use Lagrange’s theorem.

For surjective homomorphism, for each element in $\Bbb Z/ n\Bbb Z$ pick one of its preimage, then there is an isomorphism between the codomain and a subset of $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$. Then Lagrange’s theorem.

When the condition above are satisfied, you can explicitly construct required homomorphisms, hence the condition is sufficient and necessary.

Comment: For the injective $f$f we get $|f(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)|\mid |\mathbb Z/ n \mathbb Z|\Rightarrow  |f(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)|\mid n$, or not?

Comment: @MaryStar You are right.

Comment: $|f(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)|$ is not equal to $m$,is it?

Comment: @MaryStar Why not? $f$ is injective.

Comment: Ah ok! So for each $m$ and $n$ with $m\mid n$ we get such an homomorphism, right?

Comment: @MaryStar For this, you need to construct one homomorphism. What I proved is that if there is an injective homomorphism, then $m\mid n$. For the converse you need to finish the construction.

Comment: What do you mean? Could you explain this further to me?

Comment: @MaryStar What I have done: $f \colon \Bbb Z /m\Bbb Z  \to \Bbb Z / n\Bbb Z$ is an injective homomorphism $\implies m\mid n$. What I have omitted: for $m\mid n$ we can construct such an injective homomorphism.